# What is an example for non unicode character set for -Dfile.encoding=?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, non-unicode

I have a JVM. where character set as "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" . This is how UTF-8 is set. I would want to set it to a non Unicode character set.

Is there an example/value for non unicode character set so that I can set to `-Dfile.encoding=` ?

Comment: Did you have a look at the description of the [[non-unicode] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/non-unicode/info) you used for this post? It contains a few examples.

Answer (score 1):

[ TLDR => *Application encoding a confusing issue, but [this document from Oracle should help](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)*. ]

First a few important general points about specifying the encoding by setting the System Property `file.encoding` at run time:

- It's use is not formally supported, and never has been. [From a Java Bug Report in 1998](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4163515):

  > The "file.encoding" property is not required by the J2SE platform
  >   specification; **it's an internal detail of Sun's implementations and
  >   should not be examined or modified by user code**.  It's also intended
  >   to be read-only; it's technically impossible to support the setting of
  >   this property to arbitrary values on the command line or at any other
  >   time during program execution.
- There is a draft JEP (JDK Enhancement Proposal), [JDK-8187041
  Use UTF-8 as default Charset](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187041), which proposes:

  > Use UTF-8 as the Java virtual machine's default charset so that APIs
  >   that depend on the default charset behave consistently across all
  >   platforms.
- It doesn't necessarily make sense to claim that *"This application uses encoding {x}"* since there may be multiple encodings associated with an application, which can be addressed in different ways, including:

  - The file encoding for console output.
  - The file encoding of the application's source files.
  - The file encoding(s) for file I/O.
  - The file encoding of file paths.

All that said, Oracle [specify all encodings supported by Java SE 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html). I can't find a corresponding document for more recent JDK versions. Note that:

- Encodings can be environment specific, based on locale, operating system, Java version, etc.
- Almost every encoding has at least one alias. For example, the encoding name for simplified Chinese is **GBK**, but you could also use **CP936** or **windows-936**.
- Most encoding are non Unicode since Unicode encoding names contain the string "UTF".
- An encoding name can vary depending on how the application is processing files (`java.nio` APIs vs. `java.io`/`java.lang` APIs.). For example, if performing some I/O on Turkish files on Windows:

  - If the `java.nio.*` classes are used, specify **-Dfile.encoding=windows-1254** at runtime.
  - If the `java.lang.*` & `java.io.*` classes are used, specify **-Dfile.encoding=Cp1254** at runtime.

This [DZone article](https://dzone.com/articles/java-may-use-utf-8-as-its-default-charset) provides a useful piece of code to show how setting **-Dfile.encoding** at runtime can impact various settings:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Locale;
import static java.lang.System.out;
/**
 * Demonstrate default Charset-related details.
 */
public class CharsetDemo
{
   /**
    * Supplies the default encoding without using Charset.defaultCharset()
    * and without accessing System.getProperty("file.encoding").
    *
    * @return Default encoding (default charset).
    */
   public static String getEncoding()
   {
      final byte [] bytes = {'D'};
      final InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
      final InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
      final String encoding = reader.getEncoding();
      return encoding;
   }
   public static void main(final String[] arguments)
   {
      out.println("Default Locale:   " + Locale.getDefault());
      out.println("Default Charset:  " + Charset.defaultCharset());
      out.println("file.encoding;    " + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
      out.println("sun.jnu.encoding: " + System.getProperty("sun.jnu.encoding"));
      out.println("Default Encoding: " + getEncoding());
   }
}
```

Here's some sample output when specifying **-Dfile.encoding=860** (an alias for *MS-DOS Portuguese*) using Java 12 on Windows 10:

```
run:
Default Locale:   en_US
Default Charset:  IBM860
file.encoding:    860
sun.jnu.encoding: Cp1252
Default Encoding: Cp860
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Test the encoding you plan to specify at run time on all target platforms. You may get unexpected results. For example, when I run the code above on Windows 10 with **-Dfile.encoding=IBM864** (*PC Arabic*) it works, but fails with **-Dfile.encoding=IBM420** (*IBM Arabic*).